# Minimum value of f(θ)= a²sec²θ +b² cosec²θ using AM- GM inequality

Tags: functions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If we take and function

$$f(θ)= \dfrac{a^2}{\cos^2\theta} + \dfrac{b^2}{\sin^2\theta}$$

And wish to find minimum value of function using AM -GM inequality

> i.e. if we have two no. p & q
> Then    $$AM \ge GM$$
> $$\dfrac{p+q}{2}  \ge  \sqrt{pq} $$

Using here

$$\dfrac{a^2}{\cos^2\theta} + \dfrac{b^2}{\sin^2\theta} \ge 2 \sqrt { \dfrac{a²b²}{\sin^2 \theta  \cos ^2 \theta}}$$

Multiply dividing by $4$ in square root

$$\dfrac{a^2}{\cos^2\theta} + \dfrac{b^2}{\sin^2\theta} \ge 2 \sqrt { \dfrac{4a²b²}{4\sin^2 \theta  \cos ^2 \theta}}$$

> by using $$2 \sin \theta \cos \theta=\sin (2\theta) $$

$$\dfrac{a^2}{\cos^2\theta} + \dfrac{b^2}{\sin^2\theta} \ge 2 \sqrt { \dfrac{4a²b²}{\sin^2 (2\theta)}}$$

But now i am totally confused how to deal it to find minimum value of function

> Please consider case when $a>b$, $b>a $

Answer in the book is:- $(a+b)^2$

Comment: hang on, do you need the maximum or the minimum value? Please clarify with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4656267/edit)

Comment: Minimum value! brother... And I mentioned it 2 times in the question.. if still needed i can edit!

Comment: the title says the contrary

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP themselves aren't aware about the title they wrote

Comment: Hey brother , it is so difficult to me to write this answer beacuse I am not much aware with latex features and phone's keyboard problems and etc. Please edit at your own, if needed

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad I don't think you'll be able to cast close votes....

Comment: @DS you exposed me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\dfrac{a^2}{\cos^2\theta} + \dfrac{b^2}{\sin^2\theta}=a^2\tan^2\theta+b^2\cot^2\theta+a^2+b^2$$
Now by $AM\ge GM$ we see that the minimum of $a^2\tan^2\theta+b^2\cot^2\theta$ is $2ab$ $$\implies \dfrac{a^2}{\cos^2\theta} + \dfrac{b^2}{\sin^2\theta}=a^2\tan^2\theta+b^2\cot^2\theta+a^2+b^2\ge 2ab+a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2$$

## Alternative

By Cauchy Schwarz $$\dfrac{a^2}{\cos^2\theta} + \dfrac{b^2}{\sin^2\theta}\ge\frac{(a+b)^2}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}=(a+b)^2$$

Comment: Hey amazing solution exactly what I was thinking to have... But I want to know how thought came in your mind to take LCM and use (1= sin²θ + cos²θ) to make it in tan²θ and cot²θ    ... I was thinking the same because I can apply am gm inequality on a²tan²θ+b²cot²θ... But just stuck into it...

Comment: @OpenLearner I first rewrote the expression in sec and cosec then applied 1+tan^2x=sec^2x and same for the cosec one